# REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION for ncurses on Windows

Tags: c#, ncurses

Having trouble with continuously reading the mouse position from a a simple c# wrapper around Thomas Dickey's Windows build of ncurses [here](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#download_mingw-h3), I can call most of the API without any issues.

However, I can't read the mouse position except when there is a corresponding click event. My code is highly implementation-specific but the main loop of my quick-and-dirty test app looks like this (obviously `NC` is my wrapper with many static methods):

```cs
var eventMask =
    NCMouse.BUTTON1_CLICKED |
    NCMouse.BUTTON2_CLICKED |
    NCMouse.REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION;

NC.MouseMask(eventMask, out uint old);

while(true)
{
    int c = NC.GetChar();
    if(c == NCKey.MOUSE)
    {
        NC.GetMouse(out MouseEvent mouse);
        NC.MoveAddString(3, 0, $"{mouse.x}.  {mouse.y}");
    }
    else 
    if (c != -1)
    {
        break;
    }

    NC.Move(NC.Lines - 1, NC.Columns - 1);
    NC.Refresh();
}
```

From reading about *nix solutions, I suspect I may need some sort of environment variable, although I've also seen comments from C devs saying they had to `printf("\0cc[?1003h\n")` to enable mouse position reporting, then disable it before exit with a similar sequence. I suppose I'd have to pinvoke to an msvcrt DLL to try that (I didn't expect .NET's `Console.Write` to work, and it didn't).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows console-driver (which is all those binaries support) doesn't use escape sequences.  By the way, you can enable tracing by setting the [`NCURSES_TRACE`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_trace.3x.html#h3-Trace-Parameter) environment variable.

Comment: An answer from The Man Himself! Does the Windows console support continuous mouse pointer position reporting? If so, what does it take to enable it? I ran my test with `TRACE_MAXIMUM` which was interesting (especially handy to see the whole buffer dumped on refreshes, man I could have put _that_ to good use for debugging in the old days), but no answers jumped out at me.

Comment: No - the console support is only looking for button events, though reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str), I don't see anything that would prevent implementing motion-events.